# Sharepoint Requirement Login?

Tags: sharepoint, office365

I am setting up a SharePoint Online instance and I have some requirements that I do not know how to implement.

These are some of the requirements:

1. When a user logs into SharePoint, the user should select a country and city. Depending on the selected country and city, the corresponding site and subsites should appear.
2. Create folders that users cannot delete.

I don't know what is the process to create the first point and the option to disable in the second, if some of you know a tutorial or maybe knows how to do it, I would really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

(1) One approach is modifying the welcome page through SharePoint Designer to contain HTML selectors for country and city. Based on the selected country and city, you can then redirect to the proper site using JavaScript.

(2) Creating folders that users can't delete requires custom .NET code. You can't run custom .NET code directly in SharePoint Online. Depending on your requirements, you need to create the folders using a console application or a custom app part. The console app or the app part can create the folders and remove permissions on the folders.